# LCM calculation code in python outputs wrong value for very hugh inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written a small piece of code in python to calculate lcm. It works for most of values that are entered manually. however, it fails when I provide the following 2 numbers: `226553150 1023473145` (found with automatic checker)

My code calculates a value of : `46374212988031352`

Whereas expected value is : `46374212988031350`

I'm not sure what is causing this 1-digit failure. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
# Uses python3
import sys

a, b = map(int, input().split())
prod = a*b

while b:
    a, b = b, a%b

print (int(prod/a))
```

I've tried printing the prod (product) separately and that looks fine and the value of 'a' (which ultimately should hold the gcd) looks fine too. But in any case, I still keep getting the wrong answer.

When I tried to print the final answer without `int`, I get the following answer:

```
4.637421298803135e+16
```

That looks like a right answer but the formatting is not how I wanted it to be.
Can someone explain what's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do integer division like:

#### Code:

```
prod // a
```

#### Why:

The construct:

```
int(prod / a)
```

does a floating point division, then converts to an `int`.  This loses some precision.

#### Test Code:

```
a, b = 226553150, 1023473145
prod = a * b

while b:
    a, b = b, a % b

print(int(prod / a))
print(prod // a)
```

#### Results:

```
46374212988031352
46374212988031350
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this recursive code in Python where first it checks the value of second input,if it is zero then it just returns the first input value as GCD else it will have a recursive call to the GCD function.

This code is working for large numbers as well.

Here's the code:

```
def gcd(a,b):
    if(b!=0):
        return gcd(b,a%b)
    else:
        return(a)


a=int(input("Enter val of a= "))
b=int(input("Enter val of b= "))
g=gcd(a,b)
l=(a*b)//g
print("gcd of ",a ,"and", b,"is =",g)
print("lcm of",a, "and", b,"is =",l)
```

Output Link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJJ3y.png

Comment: It's a good practice on SO to explain solution. 'Try out' does not really suggests you have a definitive answer